# Overlaying pictures in one image

Tags: image, delphi

Is it possible to merge two or more different bmp-pictures of the same size into one by overlaying on top of each other? The same way it was done in Windows XP MS Paint: pasting one picture in another, with secondary color being transparent.

[image: Example]

Comment: Certainly possible. Done [a lot of that](http://english.rejbrand.se/algosim/manual/pmproc/pmproc.html) myself.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: thanks for that link and more specifically the content there. Great reference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Transparent` property of `TBitmap` to that effect. Since your bitmaps have a black border, automatic transparent color (first pixel of image data) wouldn't work and you need to also set the `TransparentColor` property to 'clWhite'.

```
var
  bmp1, bmp2: TBitmap;
begin
  bmp1 := TBitmap.Create;
  bmp1.LoadFromFile('...\test1.bmp');

  bmp2 := TBitmap.Create;
  bmp2.LoadFromFile('...\test2.bmp');

//  bmp2.PixelFormat := pf24bit;  // with 32 bit images I need this, don't know why
  bmp2.Transparent := True;
  bmp2.TransparentColor := clWhite;
  bmp1.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, bmp2);  // draw bmp2 over bmp1

  // this is how the merged image looks like
  Canvas.Draw(0, 0, bmp1);
  ..
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Just a note to someone using this code, make sure that bmp1 and bmp2 are going to be the same size. If bmp2 is smaller than bmp1, then bmp2 will be placed in the top left hand corner of the image.

Answer (score 4):

In case of the second bitmap is black-and-white, you can use it as a mask in a raster operation with [BitBlt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ( bit-block transfer), as follows:

```
  Windows.BitBlt(Bmp3.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Bmp3.Width, Bmp3.Height,
    Bmp1.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  Windows.BitBlt(Bmp3.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Bmp3.Width, Bmp3.Height,
    Bmp2.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, SRCAND);
```